# Static Array with custom Index type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to build a static Array in Haskell with a custom Enum Index type and have implemented the required functions like this:

```
data Ind = One | Two | Three | Four deriving (Eq,Ord,Enum,Show)

instance Ix Ind where
  range (m,n)             = [m..n]
  inRange (m,n) i         = m <= i && i <= n
  index b i | inRange b i = fromEnum i
            | otherwise   = -1
  rangeSize (m,n) = (index (m,n) n ) + 1
```

With this I am now trying to build a matrix type:

```
type Row a    = Array Ind a
type Matrix a = Array Ind Row a
```

However, I am getting this error on the Matrix type:

```
 Illegal type "Array Ind Row a" in constructor application
```

Could anybody explain to me what this error means and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `type Matrix a = Array Ind (Row a)`?

Comment: Ohh yes indeed, thanks! What a stupid mistake

Comment: you could also write `... deriving (Eq,Ord,Enum,Show,  Ix  )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is unhelpful, but you just need to add some brackets:

```
type Matrix a = Array Ind (Row a)
```

You're saying that the element type should be `Row a`. Without the brackets, it's trying to pass `Row` and `a` as separate type arguments — which doesn't work.